# Wordpress: what is the coindtitional tag for custom taxonomies?

Tags: wordpress

I'm learning wordpress.

In my archive.php I've several conditional tags such as :

```
if ( is_category() ) {
 ...
} elseif ( is_tag ) {
 ...
} elseif ( is_month) {
 ...
}
```

and so on

PROBLEM

I can't find a conditional tag to recognize custom taxonomies. What's the conditional tag for a custom taxonomy named 'zones'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Archive.php is basically a catch-all according to the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png).
Your taxonomy page should be `taxonomy-zones.php`. The function you are asking about is [`is_tax()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax).

Comment: Now that I'm using taxonomy.php (instead of archive.php), what's the equivalent of WP_Query( 'cat='.getCurrentCatID() ) ? Thanks.

Comment: that is done with the `tax_query` parameters for WP_Query.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters